# Network problem after upgrading to Kubuntu 15.04

Tags: wireless, upgrade, kubuntu, 15.04

This problem started to occur after I upgraded to 15.04.
I connect to wifi, after some time it disconnects, and after I try to re-connect it shows following:
[image: Wlan]
* Blured area are wifi names.

Comment: PS. After restart, wifi works fine, again for some time...

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you managed to solve it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, as Guest I am unable to edit my Answer so I put it in this post.
For me it worked out just typing:

```
sudo apt-get install -d --reinstall network-manager
sudo apt-get install -d --reinstall plasma-nm
```

Sorry for the Post before...

Cheers Kaitsh

Answer (score 0):

if that is not working try this 
`sudo sh -c 'echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" >> /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf'` 
described in  [Unstable wireless with Intel 7260 + iwlwifi after upgrade to 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616119/unstable-wireless-with-intel-7260-iwlwifi-after-upgrade-to-15-04) or [here](http://zeroset.mnim.org/2014/04/22/unstable-wifi-connection-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-ctrl-event-disconnected-reason4-locally_generated1/).

Good Luck

~Kaitsh